How can I pre-fault and lock memory pages that are mmap'd with MAP_PRIVATE?
I am writing a real-time linux application where I need to prevent any page faults from occuring after the initial startup of my application.
My initial thought was just to call mlockall(MCL_CURRENT | MCL_FUTURE);. Calling this function returns no error code, but if I inspect my process's pages, it looks like there are still many pages that have the Locked: size at 0 (which I assume means those pages can still cause a page-fault).
$ cat /proc/<pid>/smaps |  grep -B 21 -A 2 "Locked:                0 kB"  | grep -B 1 "^Size:" | grep -v "Size" | grep -v "^\-\-"
7effd0021000-7effd4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7effd4021000-7effd8000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7effd80c6000-7effdc000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7effddf02000-7effddfa0000 rw-s 00000000 00:05 368                        /dev/some_char_device
7effddfa0000-7effde1a0000 rw-s f0000000 00:05 368                        /dev/some_char_device
7effde1c1000-7effde1c2000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7effde1c6000-7effde1ca000 rw-s f7c00000 00:05 368                        /dev/some_char_device
7effde1ca000-7effde1cb000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7effe221b000-7effe221c000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7effe2220000-7effe2223000 rw-s 00000000 00:05 90                         /dev/another_char_device
7effe22df000-7effe22e0000 ---p 00013000 08:02 2234654                    /<path_to>/shared_library1.so
7effe22fd000-7effe22fe000 ---p 0000c000 08:02 2231701                    /<path_to>/shared_library2.so
7effe23fc000-7effe23fd000 ---p 0001c000 08:02 2234652                    /<path_to>/shared_library3.so
7effe2e15000-7effe2e16000 ---p 00215000 08:02 1957                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
7effe2e40000-7effe2e41000 ---p 00011000 08:02 2234649                    /<path_to>/shared_library4.so
7effe2f14000-7effe2f15000 ---p 00046000 08:02 2232115                    /<path_to>/shared_library5.so
7effe321a000-7effe321b000 ---p 0021a000 08:02 855                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30
7effe3258000-7effe3259000 ---p 0001f000 08:02 2234643                    /<path_to>/shared_library6.so
7effe327d000-7effe327e000 ---p 00021000 08:02 2234641                    /<path_to>/shared_library7.so
7effe328a000-7effe328b000 ---p 00009000 08:02 2232116                    /<path_to>/shared_library8.so
7effe348e000-7effe348f000 ---p 00102000 08:02 91759                      /<path_to>/shared_library9.so
7effe34c6000-7effe34c8000 r--p 00000000 08:02 175                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
7effe34f2000-7effe34fd000 r--p 0002c000 08:02 175                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
7ffc1d1b0000-7ffc1d1b4000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffc1d1b4000-7ffc1d1b6000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 --xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

Some attempts and some questions...
Attempt: Move the location of mlockall in the initialization function
My main function has a bunch of dlopen calls. Previously the mlockall call was after the calls to dlopen. Moving the call to mlockall before the dlopen calls seems to lock in the memory of the shared libraries that are loaded after it. However, it does not lock in the memory of shared libraries loaded before the call to mlockall (those shared libraries are linked at compile-time and specified in the executable).
Why doesn't MCL_CURRENT lock in already-loaded libraries?
$ cat /proc/<mypid>/smaps |  grep -B 21 -A 2 "Locked:                0 kB"  | grep -B 1 "^Size:" | grep -v "Size" | grep -v "^\-\-"
7fef0c021000-7fef10000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fef10021000-7fef14000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fef140c6000-7fef18000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fef1875d000-7fef187fb000 rw-s 00000000 00:05 368                        /dev/some_char_device
7fef187fb000-7fef189fb000 rw-s f0000000 00:05 368                        /dev/some_char_device
7fef18a0a000-7fef18a0b000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fef1ca2e000-7fef1ca2f000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fef1ca33000-7fef1ca37000 rw-s f7c00000 00:05 368                        /dev/some_char_device
7fef1ca37000-7fef1ca38000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fef1ca3c000-7fef1ca3f000 rw-s 00000000 00:05 90                         /dev/another_char_device
7fef1d615000-7fef1d616000 ---p 00215000 08:02 1957                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
7fef1da1a000-7fef1da1b000 ---p 0021a000 08:02 855                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30
7fef1dcea000-7fef1dceb000 ---p 00102000 08:02 91760                      /<path_to>/shared_library9.so
7fef1dd22000-7fef1dd24000 r--p 00000000 08:02 175                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
7fef1dd4e000-7fef1dd59000 r--p 0002c000 08:02 175                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
7ffece1c4000-7ffece1c8000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffece1c8000-7ffece1ca000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 --xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

Attempt: Use madvise to prefault pages
I tried calling this prefault function (inspired from here), but madvise seems to return a -1 or EPERM code on the pages with permissions ---p. If I understand correctly, those pages are mapped with MAP_PRIVATE and are supposed to be allocated in physical memory only when written to (as per the Copy-On-Write pattern). However, madvise does not seem to trigger the allocation, and just returns an error instead.
How can I pre-fault pages mapped with MAP_PRIVATE?

void prefault()
{
    const pid_t pid = getpid();
    
    FILE *fp;
    char path[PATH_MAX];
    char buf[4096];

    (void)snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "/proc/%" PRIdMAX "/maps", (intmax_t)pid);

    fp = fopen(path, "r");

    volatile uint8_t val;

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp)) {
        void *start, *end, *offset;
        int major, minor, n, ret;
        uint64_t inode;
        char prot[5];

        n = sscanf(buf, "%p-%p %4s %p %x:%x %" PRIu64 " %s\n",
            &start, &end, prot, &offset, &major, &minor,
            &inode, path);

   
        if (n < 7)        { continue; /* bad sscanf data        */ }
        if (start >= end) { continue; /* invalid addresse range */ }

        ret = madvise(start, (size_t)((uint8_t *)end - (uint8_t *)start), MADV_POPULATE_WRITE);
    }

    (void)fclose(fp);
}


For reference, this has also been asked on the Unix & Linux stack in How can I pre-fault and lock memory pages that are mmap'd with MAP_PRIVATE?

Worst case, you can execute an atomic compare-exchange once per page size to force a page-fault. It doesn't matter whether the compare-exchange succeeds, it still counts as a write operation but it does not run the risk of changing the memory content accidentally.

Does it still count as a write if you don't have permission to write to that page? Because that seems to be the issue with the ---p pages - I am getting an EPERM @Homer512

It seems like you try to populate, for writing, all mappings. But some of those mappings are obviously read-only; or just mapped but not accessible at all, as you can see in the prot column. The read-only pages can be populated for reading (MADV_POPULATE_READ or simply try to read one byte per page). The ones that are inaccessible at all, well, can't really cause a page-fault if you can never access them anyway, right?

If I understand correctly, the pages with ---p permissions are copied if written to, as they are meant to be pages with per-process data (like global variables in a shared library). As long as they are not written to, they can reference the default page, but once written to, the kernel must make a copy of that page. This is the Copy-On-Write technique. So really, they shouldn't be inaccessible right? When I write, the Linux kernel should theoretically make a copy, not return an error. @Homer512

Some sources.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868297/what-do-the-p-permissions-in-proc-self-maps-mean and https://jvns.ca/blog/2016/12/03/how-much-memory-is-my-process-using-/

@JayS. No, I don't think that interpretation is correct. If you run test code like this: https://pastebin.com/2GHMsqcD you will see that mappings that are accessible but not populated appear as rw-p or similar. Only a PROT_NONE mapping appears as ---p. Those could be guard pages or reserved address ranges (to be replaced with mmap(…, MAP_FIXED …) later) or maybe accessible memory that was then changed with mprotect. I haven't investigated that last option
